# Spring custom login form issue with Spring Security 4.0.2

Tags: spring, hibernate, security, model-view-controller, tiles

I am using Spring MVC 4.2, Hibernate 4.2.20, Apache Tiles 3.0.5 & Spring Security 4.0.2.

Well, my project was running well until I tried to use CUSTOM login page and it fails.

Please look at below page when it works with in-built login.

[image]

Now when I tried to use CUSTOM login page I get below error and nothing specific error in the console.

[image]

I am NOT sure what could be wrong. Please look at further info below.

**Project Structure**

[image]

**My Jars under /lib folder**

[image]

[image]

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringMVCHibernateProject</display-name>

    <!-- global variables -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>appRootPath</param-name>
        <param-value>SpringMVCHibernateProject</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- front controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- default page to show when app starts -->
    <!-- <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="Home"/> --> <!-- this is one way; another way defined in the HomeController.java (preferred) -->

    <!-- essentially sets you your Spring context to allow for dispatching requests to Controllers --> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- used to load static resources like css, js etc... -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>  

    <!-- automatically wire values into properties, methods, and constructors. -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- scan for components like @Controller, @Repository, @Service, @Component etc...-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="au.com.snh.*" />

    <!-- spring view resolver bean....commented out in favour of Apache Tiles -->
    <!--
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- apache tiles...template framework -->
    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>                
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <!-- load database properties file -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

     <!-- declare beans -->
    <bean id="regionDao" class="au.com.snh.dao.RegionDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="regionService" class="au.com.snh.service.RegionServiceImpl" />

    <!-- declare datasource bean -->  
     <bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />  
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />  
        <property name="password" value="${db.pwd}" />  
     </bean>

     <!-- hibernate -->
     <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="au.com.snh.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
     </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- resource bundles -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename"  value="/WEB-INF/propertybundle/common"/>     
    </bean>


    <!-- spring secruity -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <security:form-login 
                login-page="/login"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"             
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"
             />

        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>       

        <security:csrf/>

    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="hitesh" password="hitesh123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

**tiles.xml** (Apache tiles)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/Template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/Header.jsp" />     
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/Footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="login" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome to Spring MVC and Hibernate World!" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="Home" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome to Spring MVC and Hibernate World!" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/Home.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <!-- Location Views  -->
    <definition name="LocationList" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Location List" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/LocationList.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="LocationAddEdit" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Add/Edit Location" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/LocationAddEdit.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <!-- Region Views  -->
    <definition name="RegionList" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Regions" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/RegionList.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="RegionAdd" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Add Region" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/RegionAdd.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="RegionEdit" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Edit Region" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/RegionEdit.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <!-- Student Admission Views  -->
    <definition name="AdmissionForm" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Edit Region" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/AdmissionForm.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="AdmissionFormSuccess" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Edit Region" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/AdmissionFormSuccess.jsp" />
    </definition>   


</tiles-definitions>
```

**SecurityController.java**

```
package au.com.snh.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class SecurityController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
        System.out.println("login() start =>");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }

        model.setViewName("login");     
        System.out.println("login() start <=");
        return model;

    }
}
```

**My Custom Login Form**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<div id="pageHeading">Login with Username and Password</div>

<div id="bodyContent">  
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
    </c:if>

    <form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type='text' id="username" name='username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' id="password" name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>                
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("username").focus();
</script>
```

Can someone please tell me what could be wrong?

Looking forward to getting some help.

Thanks - Hitesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your login page is now a normal page displayed through `DispatcherServlet` instead of being generated by a Spring Security filter. So it **must** be accessible to non authenticated user. Currently, your security configuration requires a ROLE_USER for all pages... including `/login`. So here is what happens:

- you make a request for any page before being authenticated
- spring security detects that and redirect to `/login` page
- browser sends a request for `/login` page without being authenticated
- spring security detects that and redirect to `/login` page !

You must allow all accesses to `/login` page in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<!-- spring secruity -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" 
                            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY,IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    ...
```

alternatively, you can create a dedicated security zone for `/login` fully by-passing security:

```
<!-- spring secruity -->
<security:http pattern = "/login*" security="none">
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Serge. It's working for me now. Can you please tell me how to enable to show images and css on the /login page?

Comment: Hi Serge, just tried with <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/> and all good.

Comment: Hi Serge, I am still having one issue...I am getting an error like " HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found  " when I submit the login page. Well, I have already added the hidden field <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/> in the form. I noticed after rendering login page when I look at source it is rendered like <input type="hidden" name="" value=""/> ....Do you know why?

Comment: I assume you are using `<security:http pattern="/login*" security="none"/>`. Security filters are by-passed and csrf could not be initialized. You should try `<security:intercept-url pattern="/login" ...`, and make sure to use Spring tag `<form:form>` in your login form.

Comment: Hi Serge, so after your suggested change now at least I can see CSRF is getting generated dynamically in the view source. But when I submit nothing happens...just login page reloads again...Please see my original post above I have added custom login form at the end.

Comment: Hi Serge, even I changed my FORM ACTION to /SpringMVCHibernateProject/j_spring_security_check .......... still it does not work...just reloads the login page.

Comment: It's all working now....I just had to change the action page to " login ". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not redirecting properly

Try to add the `default-target-url`

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"  default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
```